# Convert a line of text column to a yes/no in a Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint List that has a column of the type line of text.

The column only has "Yes" and "No" as values.

Now I would like to make it a yes/no type column instead.

What's an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I created a new column of yes/no in the same list.

Using access I filtered the line of text column by Yes and made all visible lines in the auxiliary yes/no column selected.

I swapped the line of text type to number and then to yes/no.

In access I copied the value of the auxiliary column to the original one

Then I deleted the auxiliary column.

Answer (score 0):

My list had a Single line of text column with values of 0 for No and 1 for Yes. I was able to convert it to type Yes/No by first converting it to type Number. (I used the "Modern" UI--column header drop-down > Column settings > Edit.) After converting it to type Number, when I went back to change the type, Yes/No showed in the Type drop-down.